# Angular 2 Signalr

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, web-services, signalr

So I have a C# WebApi Signalr webservice with a Angular 2 Signalr Client.

The WebService is supposed to update the client when a new message comes in from a post method that other services may call.

```
[HttpPost]
        public void NotificationMessage([FromBody]ServiceInformation serviceInformation)
        {
            Messages.notificationMessage = serviceInformation;
            notificationMessage.BroadCastNotificationMessage();
        }
```

Another service posts to this method and this method sets a static variable in the Messages class and then calls the NotificationMessage Hub.

```
public class NotificationMessage : Hub<IClient>
    {
        public void BroadCastNotificationMessage()
        {
            Clients.All.serviceInfoBroadCast(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Messages.notificationMessage));
        }
    }
```

The notification hub then calls Clients.All to broadcast the new message to all clients.

Angular Site:

Service:

```
constructor() {
        this.connectionEstablished = new EventEmitter<Boolean>();
        this.messageReceived = new EventEmitter<ServiceInformationObject>();
        this.connectionExists = false;
        this.connection = $.hubConnection(CONFIGURATION.baseUrls.server);
        this.proxy = this.connection.createHubProxy(this.proxyName);

        this.registerOnServerEvents();
        this.startConnection();
    }

    private startConnection(): void {
        this.connection.start({ jsonp: true, waitForPageLoad: false}).done((data: any) => {
            console.log('Now connected ' + data.transport.name + ', connection ID= ' + data.id);
            this.connectionEstablished.emit(true);
            this.connectionExists = true;
            //this.proxy.invoke('BroadCastNotificationMessage');
        }).fail((error: any) => {
            console.log('Could not connect ' + error);
            this.connectionEstablished.emit(false);
        });
    }

    private registerOnServerEvents(): void {
        this.proxy.on('serviceInfoBroadCast', (data: string) => {
            console.log('received in SignalRService: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
            let jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
            let newData = new ServiceInformationObject(jsonData.ServiceName, jsonData.Message, jsonData.State, jsonData.MachineName, Date.now());
            this.messageReceived.emit(newData);
        });
    }
```

I setup the hub connection followed by the hub proxy. I call the proxy.on method connecting to the Clients.All dynamic method from the web service. Then I start the connection.

Component to display data on view:

```
private subscribeToEvents(): void {
        this._signalRService.connectionEstablished.subscribe(() => {
            this.canSendMessage = true;
        });
        this._signalRService.messageReceived.subscribe((message: ServiceInformationObject) => {
            this._ngZone.run(() => {
                this.testArray.push(message);
            });
        });
    }
```

The issue:
If I leave the invoke call in the startConnection method, it will pull data down from the webservice, but it will never update ever again.
If I don't use the invoke nothing happens.
I'm not sure why the webservice is not pushing the information when Clients.All is called. I know the post method is being called from my own interal logging and I know the object is not empty.
Any ideas on why the webservice is not pushing the information? Or why the client is not displaying it?